# I Want to Join two tables in DB2 using SQL based on Hostname Field on tables, but have to use some String Functions,

Tags: sql, join, db2

I Want to Join two tables in **DB2** based on Hostname Field on tables, but the problem is Hostname field contains IP addresses as well as Hostname of the server. But while considering the Hostname I have to pick the Hostname before the occurrence of first '.' where as in case of IP address I have to match with entire String.

### Table A

```
HostName | TableA_ID
abc.com    1
cdf.com    2
12.23.3.1  3
12.23.3.2  4
12.23.3.3  5
```

### Table B

```
HostName | TableB_ID 
abc.in     6
cdf.in     7
12.23.3.1  8
12.23.3.2  9
```

### Joined Table

```
HostName | TableA_ID | TableB_ID
abc        1           6
cdf        2           7
12.23.3.1  3           8
12.23.3.2  4           9
```

I have tried to implement REGEX, but seems its not working, Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
with
a (hostname, TableA_ID ) as (
  values
  ('abc.com', 1),
  ('cdf.com', 2),
  ('12.23.3.1', 3),
  ('12.23.3.2', 4),
  ('12.23.3.3', 5)
),
b (hostname, TableB_ID ) as (
  values
  ('abc.in', 6),
  ('cdf.in', 7),
  ('12.23.3.1', 8),
  ('12.23.3.2', 9)
)
select
  a.hostname, TableA_ID, TableB_ID 
from a
  inner join b on a.hostname = b.hostname
where regexp_like(a.hostname,'\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\Z')
union all
select
  a.hostname, TableA_ID, TableB_ID 
from a
  inner join b on regexp_substr(a.hostname, '\A([^.]*)')
                = regexp_substr(b.hostname,'\A([^.]*)')
where NOT regexp_like(a.hostname,'\A\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\Z')
order by hostname
```